# New Shower Head Leaking from bottom of gooseneck

Tags: plumbing, water, shower

I replaced a shower head in my home, replaced a million before.  I applied the tape, wrapped it around the grooves on the goose neck hand tightened the shower head, then put duct tape around my adjustable wrench and tightened with the wrench 2 qtr turns.  BAM!

So I thought, coming from where the arrow is, the bottom side of the new shower head, there is a contstant stream of water when the water is on.  I've got the shower head pretty tight,should I go tighter?  More tape?  What do I need to do here?

[image]

Comment: Undo everything and check for any damage, a nick, a crack, stripped threads, bad washer.  New stuff can have a defect.

Comment: oh gosh - I didn't even think about it being a "new Part" defect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your procedure is good, however too much Teflon tape can make thing leak more and even cause plastic fittings to crack. Do as crip659 advises and use less tape. Even better ditch the tape and by a tube or jar of thread sealer like Great White or Rectorseal T+2. I found it seals much better than the tape and less likely to cause a crack.

Comment: Does that work the same as using like the cpvc glue when making a connection?  Is it glue?  Meaning will I be able to remove the shower head if there are issues?

Comment: It is to be applied the same but in smaller quantity.  It is not a glue. the joints will still be able to be loosened. It's teflon and additional sealing agents, but no glues

Comment: I never use thread sealant on a shower head. The sealing washer in the head is supposed to seal against the end of the pipe coming out of the wall. These are not tapered threads in which the threads must be filled with sealant or Teflon tape. The threads are there to press the end of the pipe against the flexible seal.

Comment: @JimStewart wait wait wait....you are saying you never even use tape to add the shower head?

Comment: @user2676140 Yes, I never use tape on a shower head. The purpose of tape or pipe thread dope is to fill the spaces between the threads in connections where the threads are exposed to water. In a shower head the seal is at the end of the pipe pressing against the rubber washer. The water does not come in contact with the threads and they do not need filling with tape or dope. If tape is overhanging the end of the pipe, it can prevent the end of the pipe sealing against the rubber washer seal and cause a leak.

Comment: If the rubber seal would be missing or damaged, then tape would be necessary, but I am not sure the mating would work without the rubber seal. The threads on the shower arm and the shower head are designed to function without sealant. Tighten a little past hand tight only. This is not like a connection with NPT threaded pipe.

Comment: just installed a shower head yesterday with no washer.  (It had gone missing)  Used GreatWhite pipe sealant paste from local blue big box store. Hand tightened with no leaks. Job done.

Comment: I think i'll pick up some of that greatwhite stuff...I hand tightened, then did two qtr turns with a wrench and this is what i've got...def curious to see how the greatwhite works out